# htaccess rewrite to subdmains not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a subdomain sub.example.com to example.com/works/sub. I have the following in my htaccess file, but its not working. Please help.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,P]
```

If have also tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/works/sub/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

In both cases, I get `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` whenever I try to navigate to the page.

The funny thing is that every other rule in the htaccess file works. Including the rule that follows it immediately:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Just that first part is not working.

Comment: did you setup the subdomain DNS correctly? `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` related to DNS problem

Comment: Can you refer me to something telling me how to properly configure a subdomain dns of a domain I have changed its name server from my registrars own?

Comment: set `a` record of a subdomain same as `@` points to